# how can i restore my db schema in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle11g

I use oracle 11g , and sql develper stop working becouse of virus attack :(
THE PROBLEM is that i need to restore my database schema , the data is not important to recover , sql plus work properly , can i recover the schema from sql plus or folders of oracle program ???
pleaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaase help :(

Answer (score 0):

Why would a virus that caused SQL Developer to stop working have an impact on the database schema?  You also write that SQLPlus works.  Can you connect to the database with SQLPLus?  Please provide clearer information on what the problem is.

Comment: I used to use sql developer to manage my database , but it stop working now , and now i want to install oracle to work with sql developer , but i don't want to create all tables,views,indexes again , becouse of that i wanna know the eay to restore my db schema by sql plus , since i never used sql plus :(

Comment: SQL Developer is a tool that connects to a database, it is not part of the database.  Did SQL Developer stop working or the database?  Did you try to re-install SQL Developer and just connect to the database?

Comment: sql develper just stop working , but i don't know any other way to deal with my db but through it , i don't know even how to reinstall it only sonce all oracle setup install oracle as one package , do u know another way to reinstall sql developer alone?